# Populate a list of countries data stored in JSON file in a HTML drop down box. PHP/Javascript/AJAX - getting double values and unsorted

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am new here so I do beg your pardon if I sound base.

I am trying to create a dropdown box in HTML to populate a list of countries stored in a JSON file. The name of the countries are found in an object within another object in an array which is in an object.

I have managed to populate the countries within the dropdown box but they appear duplicated and are not in alphabetical order.

I tried using .sort() but not sure how without breaking my code.

index.html

```
<span id="selectContainer">
<select name="country" id="country" class="form-select">
<!-- populate from PHP call that returns only the codes and names from the countryborder GeoJSON file -->
<option value="">Select a country</option>
</select>
</span>
```

script.js

```
$.getJSON("./countryBorders.geo.json", function(data) {

        const result = data['features'];
        
        for (let i=0; i < result.length; i++){
            let name = result[i]['properties']['name'];
            
        $.each(data, function (key, item) {
          
            $('#country').append(
                 $('<option></option>')
                 .val(item)
                 .html(name)
             );
             
            })
        }
    });
```

A sample of the JSON file known as countryBorders.geo.json

```
{"type": "featureCollection", "features": 
[{"type": "Feature", "properties": {"name": Bahamas", "iso_a2":"BS", "iso_a3": "044"}, "geometry": {"type": "Multipolygon", "coordinates": [[ etc ]]}, 
{"type": "Feature", "properties": {"name": Mexico", "iso_a2":"MX", "iso_a3": "484"}, "geometry": {"type": "Multipolygon", "coordinates": [[ etc ]]},
{"type": "Feature", "properties": {"name": Trinidad and Tobago", "iso_a2":"TT", "iso_a3": "780"}, "geometry": {"type": "Multipolygon", "coordinates": [[ etc ]]}, 
...
```

and so forth

[pic of what my dropdown box looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YB5vy.png)

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated! Thanks in anticipation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could achieve it like this:

```
<span id="selectContainer">
  <select name="country" id="country" class="form-select">
    <option value="">Select a country</option>
  </select>
</span>
```

And your script:

```
$.getJSON("./countryBorders.geo.json", function(data) {
  const result = data['features'];
  let countryNames = [];

  // Populate the countryNames array
  for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    let name = result[i]['properties']['name'];
    countryNames.push(name);
  }

  // Sort the country names
  countryNames.sort();

  // Populate the dropdown
  for (let i = 0; i < countryNames.length; i++) {
    $('#country').append(
      $('<option></option>')
        .val(countryNames[i])
        .html(countryNames[i])
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: @orionsquare2000 If this answer answers your question, you can mark it with the green marker and upvote it.